# Shutdown PC after suspending terminal process (apt-get upgrade)

Tags: command-line, apt, kill, shutdown

What's going to happen if I shutdown my PC after suspending a terminal process (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>)? In my case, it's `sudo apt-get upgrade`. The upgrade file size is 250 MB, it takes far more time downloading those files compared to downloading some random files with the same size from websites.

So, will I lose all my downloaded data, or will it continue the download process after I turn my PC back on and resume the process with `fg` command?

Comment: Suspended processes do not survive shutting the machine down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you shut down your computer, it starts again with no program running. Depending on your desktop environment, some of the programs you were using may be started automatically when you log in again, and if the programs remember their open files then they'll have the same files open, but that's about it.

Many GUI applications are big things that do a lot, including session saving. In contrast, command line applications tend to be built on a philosophy of doing one task well, and using the shell as a glue language to control applications and tie them together. If a well-designed command line application is interrupted, running it again with the same parameters (remembered in the shell history) should finish the job. And that works for `apt-get`. Run the command again and it'll start again where it left off, or close enough.

A Debian upgrade consists of many files, with a median size of around 100 kB (the largest packages, at around 30–60 MB, are mostly large datasets and debugging information). If you interrupt the upgrade process, the files that are already fully downloaded will still be around (in `/var/cache/apt/archives`) and won't be downloaded again.

Comment: Thanks for detailed information, I don't know that downloaded files will be saved in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Answer (score 0):

`fg` the process won't work after a reboot because during the shutdown face a signal is sent to the process to kill it.

Why not do something like:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo reboot
```

Once the upgrade finishes **successfully**, the reboot command will be issued.

Answer (score 0):

> What's going to happen if I shutdown my PC
>   after suspending a terminal process?

The same thing that happens if you terminate it with `kill`. 
I would say, "The same thing that happens
if you terminate it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,"
but programs can trap that and clean up after themselves before they exit. 
(Strictly speaking, programs can trap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> too,
but not many do.) 
No, you cannot resume it with `fg`.

If you're asking specifically about `apt-get`,
you should edit your question to make it clear
that `apt-get` is the focus of the question
and not just an arbitrary example.